# Fade in when hidden

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to fade in an object into my game when I first touch the screen, but I think that because it was hidden before (when game was launched), it won't fade in, but only show without any animation.

Do you have any suggestions?

This is an example code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var myLabel = SKLabelNode()
    var gameStarted = Bool()

    func setupMyLabel(){
        myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
        myLabel.fontSize = 35
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        setupMyLabel()
        self.addChild(myLabel)
        myLabel.hidden = true

        gameStarted = false
    }

    func startGame(){
        myLabel.hidden = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        if gameStarted == false{

            gameStarted = true

            startGame()
            self.myLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(2.0))
        }
        else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use `alpha = 0.0` instead of `hidden = true` ?

Comment: Then it works, haha. Thank you!! I changed `hidden` to `alpha` and instead of `fadeInWithDuration`, I used `fadeAlphaTo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeInWithDuration:) on `fadeInWithDuration` it states that:

> When the action executes, the node’s alpha property animates from its
>   current value to 1.0.

So you're right in thinking it's because your node is hidden when it starts. =)

One possible solution would be to instead of setting the node's hidden property to true, instead set it's alpha value to 0. Or you could even create your own method to perform that includes the `runAction` method that would set the alpha to 0, un-hide the node, and then call `SKAction.fadeInWithDuration` similar to something below (please forgive any syntax errors, this is free-hand pseudo code)...

```
startGame()
self.fadeIn(self.myLabel, duration: 2.0)

...

func fadeIn() {
    self.myLabel.alpha = 0.0
    self.myLabel.hidden = false
    self.myLabel.runAction(SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(2.0))
}
```

Comment: The alpha method worked just fine, but on the second way, xcode instructed me to change `UILabel` for `Optional <SKLabelNode>` and it was still showing `myLabel` without any animation.

Comment: Oh you're right, I completely overlooked the fact that self.myLabel was a SKLabelNode. If instead of passing in the label and duration you just removed the if check and referenced self.myLabel, does it still not animate?

Comment: Sorry, I just did it haha. You can refuse it, if you want.

Comment: Lol no worries, Stackoverflow actually auto refused. I didn't know it did that!